# Limit of sequences: $ \lim (1 + \frac{r}{n} )^n = e^r $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence $x_n =  \left (1+\frac{r}{n} \right )^n $ for $r \in \mathbb{Q} $. I need to prove that $ \lim x_n = e^r $

My attempt of proof (for r>0) is to find a subsequence of $x_n$ that converges to $e^r$, but it will be enough if $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since all the convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences, I was thinking to prove that $x_n$ is convergent and it will finish my problem. So if I prove that that $x_n$ is increasing and  have an upper bound ($3^r$, for example), then it is done. But I'm having trouble with this last step.

But maybe it is easier to prove using, for example, that $\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n/r}\right)^n$ but I don't see how to proceed too.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you defining $e$?

Comment: try to work with the sequence of $log(x_n)$

Comment: @oldrinb $e =: \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)$ for n a **natural number**

Comment: @ALW I don't see how this can make the proof easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the following definitions. $\log$ is defined as
$$
\log(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, dt.
$$
for all $x > 0$. From this definition it can be shown that all the familiar properties of $\log$ holds. $e^x$ is defined as $e^x = \log^{-1}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (it can be proved that $\log$ is increasing so its one to one and maps onto $\mathbb{R}$, so the inverse exists). Then $e$ is defined as $e = e^1 = \log^{-1}(1)$.

Now I will prove the limit. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\log'(\frac{1}{r}) = r$. Using the definition of derivatives, we have
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(\frac{1}{r} + h) - \log(\frac{1}{r})}{h} = r \\
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\log(1 + rh) = r \\
\lim_{h \to 0} \log\left((1 + rh)^{\frac{1}{h}}\right) = r.
$$
Since $\log$ is continuous, we can write
$$
\log\left(\lim_{h \to 0} (1 + rh)^{\frac{1}{h}}\right) = r \\
\lim_{h \to 0} (1 + rh)^{\frac{1}{h}} = e^r.
$$
So we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{r}{n})^n = e^r \\$ where the expression inside the limit is a function. So it must also be true for the sequence with integer $n$.

---

**EDIT:**

Let $a_n = \left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n$. This sequence is increasing. To see this, note that $(1 + a)^b \geq 1 + ab$ (by binomial theorem). Apply this for $a = \frac{r}{n + 1}$ and $b = \frac{n + 1}{n}$ to get
$$
\left(1 + \frac{r}{n + 1}\right)^{\frac{n + 1}{n}} \geq 1 + \frac{r}{n + 1} \cdot \frac{n + 1}{n} = 1 + \frac{r}{n}.
$$
Taking both sides to the power of $n$ gives $\left(1 + \frac{r}{n + 1}\right)^{n + 1} \geq \left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n$ which shows that the sequence is increasing. To show that it is bounded, first use the binomial theorem to get
$$
\left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} \left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^i = \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!(n - i)!} \cdot \frac{r^i}{n^i} \\
= \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{r^i}{i!} \left(\frac{n(n - 1) \dotsb (n - i + 1)}{n^i}\right) \leq \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{r^i}{i!}.
$$
since $n(n - 1) \dotsb (n - i + 1) \leq \underbrace{n \dotsb n}_{i} = n^i$. So
$$
\left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n \leq \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{r^i}{i!} < \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{r^i}{i!}.
$$
But the series on the right most side converges which we can check by the ratio test. So $a_n$ is bounded by that number. Thus $a_n$ converges since it is increasing and bounded.

Comment: thanks for the help but I can't use the logarithm is a continuous function to apply log in my limit since I don't have this property yet. Since we are studying limit of sequences, we have to admit that we didn't see limits, integrals and derivatives

Comment: that is exatly what I was doing! But I don't see why this series necessary converges. I stopped my demonstration exatly there

Comment: @user2768645 The series converges by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Let the terms in the series be $b_i = \frac{r^i}{i!}$. Then the ratio of two consecutive terms is $\frac{b_{i + 1}}{b_i} = \frac{r^{i + 1}}{(i + 1)!} \cdot \frac{i!}{r^i} = \frac{r}{i + 1}$ and so $\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{b_{i + 1}}{b_i} = \lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{r}{i + 1} = 0 < 1$. So the infinite series converges.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $e = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, then you have (for $r\neq 0$)
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{r}}\right)^{\frac{n}{r}r} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{kr} = e^r$$
where we have written $k=\frac{n}{r}$.

Comment: He already knows if it converges it will converge to $e^r$. He is asking how to prove it converges at all.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I can not say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n/r} \right)^{n/r} = e $ since I don't know it "officially". It is something more basic, using the properties of convergence and sequences. So I just know it for natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the definition $e =: \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n $for $r \in \Bbb Q $ and $n \in \Bbb N $, choose your sub-sequence $m \in \Bbb N $  such that $n/r = m$  is a natural number the take $m \to \infty$ to get $e^r$ like in Daniel Robert-Nicoud's answer.

**EDIT::**
It is given that 
$a_n = \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n$ converges to $e$. let $m \in \Bbb N $ be a subsequence of $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $m/r = n$ a natural number. $x_n = \left( 1 + \frac r n \right)^n$, then take sub-sequence $x_m$ of $x_n$, you get 
$x_m = \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^m =  \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{nr } = (a_n)^r$. We know that $a_n$ converges to $e$. Now it remains to show that, $\{(a_n)\}^r$ converges to $e^r$.

It is also given that $r$ is a rational number, so let $r = \frac{p}{q} \;, p, q \in \Bbb N$.
\begin{align*}
\left | a_n^r  - e^r\right | &= \left|(a_n^{1/q})^p - (e^{1/q})^p\right| \\ 
 & \le \left|(a_n^{1/q}) - (e^{1/q})\right|\cdot |p e^{(p-1)/q}|\\ 
 & \le |a_n - e| \cdot \frac{q e^{q-1}}{\sum_{k=0}^{q-1} e^{k/q}} \\ 
 &< \epsilon \\ 
\end{align*}
for some $n \ge N \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did (as i said, I found a subsequence that converges to $e^r$. But why is that enough? Don't we have to check it is a cauchy sequence before? The sequence (0,1,0,2,0,3,0...) has a subsequence that converges to 0 and it doesn't converges at all

Comment: @user2768645 given that you know $a_{n} = \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n $ is a Cauchy sequence, $a_{m} = \left( 1 + \frac 1 m \right)^m $ (being subsequence of $a_n$) is also a Cauchy sequence. We know from a theorem that every Cauchy sequence has only one limit point and every sub-sequence of Cauchy sequence is Cauchy. These two statements imply that they converge to same limit so finding the limit point of sub-sequence is enough.

Comment: a subsequence of $ a_n $ (as you called, $a_m$) still a subsequence where m is a natural number. But $x_n = \left(1+ \frac{r}{n}\right)^m $ is not a subsequence of $a_n$ . But yes, the subsequence you used to calculate the limit is, indeed, a subsequence of $a_n$, but I need that $x_n$ converges, not $a_m$

Comment: @user2768645 okay you agree that $a_{m}$ converges to $e^{r}$. this implies $|a_{m}  - e^{r}| < \epsilon $ for some $m\ge M \in \Bbb N $ which is the definition of convergence. Both for subsequence $a_m$ and the sequence $a_n$.

Comment: yes, I do agree but as I said (0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,...,0,n,..) is aslo a sequence with a convergent subsequence that not converges. Why $a_m$ convergent implies $x_n$ convergent?

Comment: @user2768645 refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence)
$\displaystyle |a_n - e^{r}| \le |a_n-a_m| + |a_m - e^{r}| \le 2 \epsilon $ for $m,n \ge N $ for some $N \in \Bbb N $. It clearly shows the convergence of $a_n$

Comment: @user2768645 because that is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: experiment, you are using that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence for prove it. If I had that $x_n$ was a cauchy sequence, I didn't have to prove it converges, because I know it does.

Comment: that is the point. I **need** to prove that $x_n = \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n $ is a Cauchy sequence. That is what I am trying to prove. I just can apply your demonstration if I know it

Comment: Experiment, you just showed that $x_m$, a subsequence of $x_n$ is convergent (what you already did when you calculated the limit). But we need to show that $x_n$ converges, not $x_m$. If $x_m$ is convergent, it doesn't mean that so does $x_n$ (By the way, thank you very much for trying to help!)

Comment: @user2768645 just realized that ... adding the part of convergence too.

Comment: Ok! I just tried to use the "trick" to show the convergence of $a_n$ but I couldn't figure out how to do it

Comment: @user2768645 we will use monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok, I will be waiting your new attempt of proof.

Comment: We just need to treat the case for r>1 (I don't know if it helps), because if 0<r<= 1 we know that $ x_n \leq a_n $

Comment: @user2768645 Did you already prove that the sequence $a_n = \left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing? I found a way to show that it is bounded.

Comment: @user2768645 I proved that the sequence is also increasing. I will add it to my existing answer.