# Show that $ x_n = \left(1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^n $ has an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515821/limit-of-sequences-lim-1-fracrn-n-er) question but maybe my doubt was not enough clear. So I will ask something more specific: Show the sequence $x_n = \left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^n$ for $ r \in \mathbb{Q}, r>0$ has an upper bound.

I tried to show it as we do for $a_n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n $ (using the expansion of $a_n$ but I had no sucess.

I would like some hint!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $\log(x)\leq x-1$ which is clear from the symmetry with the inverse function $\text e^x\geq x+1$ it follows that
$$
0\leq \log(x_n)=n\ \log\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)\leq r
$$
showing that $x_n$ is bounded. In fact this shows that $1\leq x_n\leq \text{e}^r$. Also it should be noted here that $\log(x)$ is an increasing function thus preserving inequalities.

Comment: I didn't understand your last step in the inequality: n.log(...) <= r

Comment: @user2768645: I applied $\log(x)\leq x-1$ with $x=1+\frac{r}{n}$ showing that $\log(x)\leq \frac{r}{n}$ which then multiplied by $n$ equals $r$.

Comment: Hm ok, your answer is clearly correct. I was looking for something more basic than use the logarithm function (since we are talking about the limit of sequences) but I think this solves my problem for now.

Comment: @user2768645: Since your sequence converges to $\text{e}^r$ I do not entirely see how $\log(x)$ should be considered not basic in this context. I did not say simple though ;)